# How can I alter column name in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table Amount, having a column name amount_id which i want to change and update into account_id

I am using sp_rename function but i dont know how exactly i can change it

EXEC sp_rename 'Amount.Amount_id', 'Account_id', 'COLUMN';

This is the error given

Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

Comment: is amount the schema or database?

Comment: Is it mysql or SQL Server?  Please choose the correct tag.

Comment: The syntax is fine and using your exact code works correctly on a test table.

Comment: Have you tried adding a schema name. like 'dbo.Amount.Account_id'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the syntax to rename a table. For rename a column you need

```
  EXEC sp_rename '<Schema>.<Table>.<Fieldname>, 'newfield', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: And sir what is Schema here? if you can Explain please, My database name is SqlBook

Comment: usually the dafault schema is "dbo" so 'dbo.Amount.Amount_id'

Comment: Done Sir, Thank You so much, I checked the schema in the table properties, it is "dbo"

Answer (score 3):

There are few possible ways of doing this in MSSQL server.

1. Select the table abn list the columns by click on the + in the table columns. Then right click and rename the column name
2. Go to the design of the table and then rename the column/ datatype, add new column, etc.
3. Use sp_rename system stored procedure to rename the table column name. this can be used to change the table name as well.

   ```
   sp_rename 'table.column_name', 'new_columnName', 'COLUMN';
   sp_rename 'Accounts.Marker', 'Markers', 'COLUMN';
   ```

Answer (score -3):

The syntax mentioned above should work in SQL Server. If you are using MySQL, the following syntax should work:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE `oldcolname` `newcolname` datatype(length);
```

Comment: question is about mcrosoft sql server, not MySQL